# Optimizing multiprocessing.Pool with expensive initialization

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-multiprocessing, pool, object-initializers

Here is a complete simple working example

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        # some expensive set up function in the real code
        self.x = 2
        print('initializing')

    def run(self, y):
        time.sleep(random.random() / 10.)
        return self.x + y


def f(y):
    foo = Foo()
    return foo.run(y)


def main():
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    for result in pool.map(f, range(10)):
        print(result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I modify it so Foo is only initialized once by each worker, not every task?  Basically I want the init called 4 times, not 10.  I am using python 3.5

Comment: Would it be fine if the class was initialized just once, and then copied to each worker?

Comment: @BrendanAbel I think so.  That means the object must be pickleable?  The object is never mutated after initialization so I don't know why copying would be bad

Comment: Multiprocessing is *not* the same as multithreading. They have vastly different characteristics.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in the question title

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The intended way to deal with things like this is via the optional `initializer` and `initargs` arguments to the `Pool()` constructor.  They exist precisely to give you a way to do stuff exactly once when a worker process is created.  So, e.g., add:

```
def init():
    global foo
    foo = Foo()
```

and change the `Pool` creation to:

```
pool = mp.Pool(4, initializer=init)
```

If you needed to pass arguments to your per-process initialization function, then you'd also add an appropriate `initargs=...` argument.

Note:  of course you should also remove the

```
foo = Foo()
```

line from `f()`, so that your function *uses* the global `foo` created by `init()`.

Comment: Can you please explain the global keyword in this context.  I saw the initializer in the docs but didn't think/know about "global" so I didn't see how to make it work.  Thanks

Comment: See my edit just now:  you also need to _use_ the `foo` created by the initialization function.  The initialization function runs once and ends, so any change it makes has to be visible at global scope so that other functions later (such as invoked by `map()`) can benefit.

Comment: No.  Nothing is shared across processes.  `global` has been in Python since day 1, many years before `multiprocessing` was even an idea for a module.  `global` has nothing to do with processes (or threads).  In context, it's simply telling `init()` to bind `foo` in the module's global scope instead of in (the default) `init`'s local scope.  In multiprocessing, each process has its own, distinct module global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

most obvious, lazy load

```
_foo = None
def f(y):
    global _foo
    if not _foo:
       _foo = Foo()
    return _foo.run(y)
```

Comment: Why you have a global `_foo` that is never referenced?